# Adding Multiple Graphics to different buttons in a .css file (JavaFX)

Tags: java, css

This is my first time (and question) on here.
I'm making a program that is working pretty well, except I want to define the style of different buttons differently. I am working in `JavaFX`, and defining the style of different things with a `.cs`s file. I searched about it but wasn't really sure how to set multiple images for the same type of element (if that's how you would call it; in my case, it's a button). I have 4 `buttons` that I want to define separately in the `.css` file (with different images). I have this so far for the first button:

css (gameTestCSS.css):

```
.button{
-fx-graphic: url("https://smashboards.com/proxy.php?image=http%3A%2F%2Fi.imgur.com%2F5cgHjwu.png&hash=113d5b8f78bcfb3660ec25d47ef1e5d7");
```

JavaFX (GameTest.java):

```
Button btn = new Button();
btn.getStylesheets().add(this.getClass().getResource("gameTestCSS.css").toExternalForm());
```

However, this is only for 1 button. I have another button:

```
button btn1 = new Button();
```

and would like to style it differently from the first one (a different graphic):

```
.button{
-fx-graphic: url("https://smashboards.com/proxy.php?image=http%3A%2F%2Fi.imgur.com%2F1WQpSsL.png&hash=9c7b71d564e2b1d8ee6ee0aae27fb7d9");
```

I have no idea how to go about doing it properly, since if I include both of the `.css` codes I posted above, it will only apply the second image to both buttons when I use `button.getStyleSheets()`.

I don't know if I asked this properly, or if this should belong on here, but I needed a little help with this problem I'm facing. This is my first question on here, so please bear with me if I have any mistakes in the formatting or the like. Thanks a lot in advance! :)

Comment: `.button` is for every button, as far as I'm aware. You can do `btn.setStyleClass("className")` and in your css have `.className` as your selector.

Comment: @MichaelPickett Thanks for your answer! Could you elaborate a bit more on the `.setStyleClass` method? I tried doing it simply but got an error (probably on my side, haha). So if I have the following selectors in the `.css` file:
.button1

//code (set the graphic)

.button2

//code (set the graphic)
How would I go about applying them to the different buttons? Thanks a lot :D, also apologies for the formatting, not sure how to do it properly in comments!

Comment: I possibly forgot a step. Im not at my comp so I cant test it correctly. Try doing `btn.getStyleClass().add("className")`. I believe i forgot the middle part

Comment: @MichaelPickett worked like a charm! Thanks so much for the help! It looks pretty cool :D http://i.imgur.com/TIHbolg.png (will be adding the rest later) Thanks again!!

Comment: Anytime. Looks great.

Answer (score -1):

You can change the look of every button individually

```
Button button = new Button("Pocho");
button.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#D3D3D3;");

Button button1 = new Button("Pocho1");
button1.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#000000;");
```

Comment: That defeats the purpose of using the CSS.